# OSX capture screen at pre-login session

Tags: c, macos, daemon

I want to dev a daemon which will capture screen of my OSX at pre login session

I have try by using Quazt display service (stream) and core graphic framework but it still unavailable

my code using Quartz service

```
 m_isExit = FALSE;
m_display = kCGDirectMainDisplay; // 1
m_displayMode = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(m_display);
if (m_display == NULL)
{
    throw Exception("OSX-Quart service Can not get Display mode ",VF_ERR_SCREEN_MONITOR_OSX_QUART_CREATE);
}

m_height = CGDisplayModeGetHeight(m_displayMode);
m_width = CGDisplayModeGetWidth(m_displayMode);


m_stream = CGDisplayStreamCreate(m_display,m_width,m_height,'BGRA',NULL,VncStreamFrameAvailableHandler);
if (m_stream == NULL)
{
    throw Exception("OSX-Quart service  Can not create Stream",VF_ERR_SCREEN_MONITOR_OSX_QUART_CREATE);
}

m_screenMonitorThread.start(*this);
```

it's always through exception.
Another code using Core Graphic framework

```
    m_mainDisplay = kCGDirectMainDisplay;
    m_oriImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(m_mainDisplay);
    if (m_oriImage == NULL)
    {
        throw Exception ("Core Graphic Can not Create original Image from display",VF_ERR_SCREEN_MONITOR_OSX_CG_CREATE);
    }
    ScreenGetConfigure(m_oriImage);
    screenData.m_oriImage = m_oriImage;
    m_oriPixelDataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(m_oriImage));

    if (m_oriPixelDataRef == NULL)
    {
        throw Exception ("Core Graphic Can not get pixel data ref",VF_ERR_SCREEN_MONITOR_OSX_CG_CREATE);
    }
```

Both code is not working at pre-login session.
Hope somebody can help me to fix the issue

MacBook, OS X El Capitan (10.11)

Comment: Doesn't it exists some kind of screen grabbing at pre-login? Don't really know for Aqua but it is very common, for security reasons, to forbid concurrent accesses to screen/keyboard before login...

Comment: Would you like to help me specific what document I need to research about the field. Thank

Comment: @TruongKevin Did you find a solution. Please share details

Comment: @tunafish24 It quite long time ago. Sorry for late reply. 
But I do remember about it. 
The reason here is about permission. We need to register the service as root permission then It can run at pre-login.  and we need to terminate the service (root account) when user login and transfer to user service . Hope it help